# how to recover an instance disappeared in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I had an instace VM called "wp-nginx-ssl-bitnami-vm-vm" but it disappeared. It no longer appears on the instances page. paid the platform normally without interruptions.
I didn't find any log record about instance deletion. she just disappeared. how do i recover?

Comment: Contact GCP support. If there are no logs or any actionable info StackOverflow community wont be able to help much. However GCP may have internal logs and more-info to help you out.

Comment: What log did you look in? The audit logs record that type of activity. Your instance did not just disappear. Create a list of all Project IDs. Then use the CLI to list compute instances in each project: `gcloud compute instances list --project=PROJECT_ID`.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the answer by @john-hanley

Additionally, if perhaps the instance is in another project, you can list all the projects that have Compute Engine service enabled and all their instances using:

```sh
# Compute Engine service name
COMPUTE="compute.googleapis.com"

# List of projects accessible to the current account
PROJECTS=$(\
  gcloud projects list \
  --format="value(projectId)")

# Iterate over them
for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  # Look for projects where Compute Engine is enabled
  ENABLED=$(\
      gcloud services list \
      --enabled \
      --filter="config.name=${COMPUTE}" \
      --format="value(config.name)" \
      --project=${PROJECT})
  # If it is
  if [ "${ENABLED}" = "compute.googleapis.com" ]; then
    # Output the Project(ID) and the list of instances
    echo "${PROJECT}:"
    gcloud compute instances list \
    --format="list(name)" \
    --project=${PROJECT}
  fi  
done
```

Comment: That is a nice script. I will be adding that to my collection.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately filtering with `--filter=name=${NAME}` has issues if Compute Engine if s enabled but contains no instances, so I dropped that part.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The following information is valid only if the instance deletion happened less than 30 days ago unless you previously set up [custom log retention](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/buckets#custom-retention) to keep logs for a longer period of time.

Google Cloud Compute instances do not suddenly disappear. Google Cloud records activity such as creating an instance (compute.instances.insert) and deleting an instance (compute.instances.delete) in the activity logs.

Use the following steps to investigate the issue of the missing instance. Once you know what has or has not happened, you might have a better change of figuring out a strategy.

To find the logging event for when the instance was deleted, execute the following command which will output the log details in JSON.

```
gcloud logging read 'protoPayload.methodName:"compute.instances.delete"' \
--project=GCP_PROJECT_ID \
--format=json
```

If the output is empty, then the instance was either deleted outside the logs retention period, has not been deleted or did not exist in the specified Project ID.

Note: replace `compute.instances.delete` with `compute.instances.insert` to find the creation time if that event is still in the logs.

The log entry will contain information on when the event happened:

```
"receiveTimestamp": "2021-06-10T01:33:46.314371022Z",
```

Who deleted the instance:

```
"protoPayload": {
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
  "authenticationInfo": {
    "principalEmail": "someone@example.com"
  },
```

And details on the caller's IP and User Agent:

```
  "requestMetadata": {
    "callerIp": "78.123.234.111",
    "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 ..."
  },
```